# Where to put attributes in link_to block

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to put the title in the html_options [as described in the docs:](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to)

```
link_to shop_path(@shop, html_options = {title: "Hola el mundo") do
    content_tag( :span, "Hello", class: "some_class") + " " +
    content_tag( :span, truncate(@shop.name, length: 37))
end
```

But it doesn't work. Where do I put the title attribute in a link_to block?

Comment: You are using the format of the doc's declaration to form your call. the parameter `html_options =...` is just supposed to be the hash. `html_options =...` is part of the method's declaration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML attributes can be passed as options for `link_to`, not the `_path` helper like you have:

```
link_to shop_path(@shop), title: "Hola el mundo" do
  content_tag( :span, "Hello", class: "some_class") + " " +
  content_tag( :span, truncate(@shop.name, length: 37))
end
```